# sed fails when running during jenkins process

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, jenkins, sed

I'm running a script that works locally. But when I run the script during our jenkins build process sed doesn't work.

this is my code I verified the path is correct. The file is there.
 `sed -i '' "s|$line|var bagVer = $PACKAGE_VERSION;|"  "$PWD"`

`sed: can't read s|var bagVer = "1.53.0";|var bagVer = \"1.58.0\";|: No such file or directory`

I feel like this has something to do with my syntax. But this works locally, so what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the **SPACE** between the `-i` and the two single quotes (`'`) from your sed command.  Often, the suffix must immediately follow the `-i` option with no spaces.

```
sed -i' ' "s|$line|var bagVer = \"$PACKAGE_VERSION\";|"  "$PWD"
```

Comment: So if I pull out the `' '` then I get this error running locally `sed: 1: "/Users/b003443/desktop/ ...": undefined label '003443/desktop/newthing/thing/client/app/js/models/badModel‌​'` .  `sed -i "s|$line|var bagVer = $PACKAGE_VERSION;|"  ${PWD}`

Comment: @Craig I'm going to guess you're on OSX?  Can you confirm?  Have updated answer in anticipation.

Comment: Correct I am on OSX

Comment: That actually worked however I need to add " around the $PACKAGE_VERSION how do I escape the `"` ?                        `sed -i' ' "s|$line|var bagVer = "$PACKAGE_VERSION";|"  "${PWD}"`

Comment: I figured it out `sed -i' ' "s|$line|var bagVer = \"$PACKAGE_VERSION\";|"  "${PWD}"`

Comment: Actually Kind Stranger `sed -i'' "s|$line|var bagVer = $PACKAGE_VERSION;|"  input-file` doesn't work locally I needed a space in between the `' '`