# sed fails on jenkins, but works locally

Tags: jenkins, sed, terminal, continuous-integration, sh

This command seems to work locally, but fails on jenkins

```
sed -i '' "s/\/styleguide//g" .gitignore
```

It is a parse error, despite it saying it can't find the file. I know this, because running `cat` prints the file contents. thoughts anyone?

```
sed: can't read s/\/\styleguide//g: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed fails when running during jenkins process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741698/sed-fails-when-running-during-jenkins-process)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the GNU implementation of `sed`, you must not put a space between the `-i` and the `''`, write like this:

```
sed -i'' "s/\/styleguide//g" .gitignore
```

Comment: Actually `-i''` becomes `-i` after quote removal, though including it for human readers might still be useful.